# How do I call ICDBurn::GetRecorderDriveLetter() in VS2008 C++? (Solving XP CD write to root)

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-xp, cd-burning, cd-rom

I am trying to implement the solution given in

[GetSaveFileName() not returning path of CD burning staging area on XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118667/getsavefilename-not-returning-path-of-cd-burning-staging-area-on-xp)

I'm trying to implement this in VS2008 C++.  The ICDBurn::GetRecorderDriveLetter() method is not static and thus cannot be called as written (**ICDBurn::GetRecorderDriveLetter**) in the above answer.  ICDBurn can't be instantiated because it's an abstract class.  How do I call **ICDBurn::GetRecorderDriveLetter()** from C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the COM object first.

```
ICDBurn* pICDBurn;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CDBurn, NULL,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_ICDBurn,(LPVOID*)&pICDBurn);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{

// do something ...
pICDBurn->Release();

}
```