# How to programatically determine if a drive is DVD-RW/CD-RW under Windows?

Tags: c, winapi, visual-c++, device, drive

I want to block the user to backup files to optical discs, so I have to determine if a CDROM drive is writable.

How to do under Windows?

Comment: You can do it using
GetRecorderDriveLetter

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825944/how-do-i-call-icdburngetrecorderdriveletter-in-vs2008-c-solving-xp-cd-wr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method used by open-source CD/DVD recording application [InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/) ([git repo](http://sourceforge.net/p/infrarecorder/code)).

InfraRecorder is using [ckmmc](https://github.com/kindahl/ckmmc) library to get list of compatible devices using `ckmmc::DeviceManager` class (it supports multiple devices, of course).

First it scans for all devices using ckmmc `DeviceManager::scan()`, and then checks if device is a recorder using method `MmcDevice::recorder()`.

You would think that there must be easier way to do this using something like `GetDriveType()` or `DeviceIoControl()`, but unfortunately it is not that simple.

`ckmmc` supports two different device access methods: ASPI (Advanced SCSI Programming Interface) and SPTI (SCSI Pass-Through Interface). To get drive properties it actually sends SCSI commands to the device, and only then it can analyze SCSI mode page and tell which recording modes (CD-R, CD-RW, DVD-R, DVD+R, etc...) hardware supports (if any).

Comment: DeviceIoControl() can be used to send ASPI/SPTI commands directly, and it is not TOO difficult to do without ckmmc. I've done it before to locate DVD-specific drives and inserted discs.

Comment: I guess if one is really so inclined, it should be possible to extract just this bit from ckmmc and have it as separate function

Comment: I had never heard of ckmmc before seeing this discussion, otherwise I would have used it instead back then :-)

Answer (score 3):

The drive index (0 = A, 1 = B, etc) for the Windows CD burner can be found in the registry at **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CD Burning\DriveIndex**.

Comment: What if there are two CD burners?

Comment: Windows itself doesn't support more than one burner. Third party tools might, however. If you want to block those as well you would need to use something more low-level to query the drive type.

Comment: Note: Using the ICDBurn interface as suggested by @Vahid Farahmand is probably better than reading the registry.

Answer (score 1):

As this page explains:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

GetRecorderDriveLetter will return drive letter which is a burner (if exists) or it will return an error code if there is no drive which could burn a CD.

If you need more samples, just search the API